# Display a grid of thumbnails lazily like in SlickGrid's DataView

Tags: html, grid, slickgrid

I really like the way SlickGrid DataView smoothly scrolls and renders/hides stuff for me.  I'd love it if I could use this same sort of behavior to display data that is slightly less tabular in format.  For example, a thumbnail gallery with thousands of thumbnails in it.

The main problem is I'd need display my list of items in a grid horizontally as well as vertically.  I suppose it could be accomplished with a dataview by dynamically changing the number of columns based on the size of the window, though this seems kind of an abuse of the system.  Is there a better system for this out there?

Comment: +1 I have the same problem. The virtualisation is fantastic but I'd like custom rendering in a gallery style.  I looked at http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example8-alternative-display.html but that example seems limited to rendering each record in a completely new row. And it looks like floating the divs would mess up the height calculations.

Comment: You can apply similar styling to display multiple cells, but it still needs to be tabular.

Comment: @njr well it's your lucky day because I just wrote this myself.

Comment: @Tin feel free to use my implementation in SlickGrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing it myself.  [Enjoy!](https://github.com/nickretallack/SlickGriddle)

Comment: Hahaha, love the name!
Btw, you might want to include some examples and put them on the wiki.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this out and let you know how I get on. As @Tin said, a complete example would be very helpful; my suggestion would be to take this example (http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example8-alternative-display.html) and modify it to use your gallery view. That would be make it easy to follow for anyone coming from SlickGrid. P.S. Yeah, great name ;)